# Multiple test correction procedures for multiple regression with dependent predictors

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value, references, multiple-comparisons, simulation

A researcher is employing OLS multiple regression to examine the independent effects (i.e., partial correlations) of a moderate (~8) number of theoretically-relevant predictors on some outcome. The researcher would like to minimize false positive findings by performing some multiple testing procedure and would like to determine the procedure prior to running the analysis. However, the predictors in her model are non-trivially correlated.

**Given the covariance matrix of the predictor variables (excluding the outcome variable), is their a sensible/accepted way to *a priori* determine a reduced p-value threshold for tests of the partial effects of the predictors?**

It seems reasonable to run a simulation where, on each iteration, data is generated based on the multivariate-normal distribution implied by the sample covariance matrix. The "true" partial effect each predictor on the outcome is null and any observed partial correlations would represent false positives. The p-value threshold used to determine "significance" in the actual study would be that which restricts the empirical p-value of the simulations to .05.

Is this a reasonable procedure given that the data from which the covariance structure is obtained come from a large sample with reliable measures? What are the "accepted" procedures for addressing this issue?